# updating UI element after gpio button press

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I'm making an application that updates a UI element after a press on a button connected to the GPIO pins.
it's my first time working with windows iot core.
I thought it would be as easy as this "lblQuestion.Text = "Button works!";" but it isn't.
can anyone tell me what I have to add for it to work correctly?

I'm recieving this error:
System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

Answer (score 1):

Please use following code to to marshal calls coming from non-UI threads.

```
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            lblQuestion.Text = "Button works!
        });
```

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject.dispatcher) describes the reason why you need to create a [DependencyObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject) on a UI thread.

Comment: You are welcome. Please let me know if it helps you fix the issue.

Comment: Please accept the response as answer, it will be helpful for developers who encounter the similar issue. Thanks.